# Does Github GraphQL return commit parents in a particular order?

Tags: git, github, graphql, github-graphql

According to the documentation (https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/objects#commit), the parents function returns "the parents of a commit." Are these sorted the same way as in git? For example, if I merge branch B into branch A, will the first parent of the merge commit be from branch A?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you can order in whatever way you like. i.e. the order you mention above, or the reverse order by using the `first` and `last` arguments. You can use the following query over at [GitHub's GraphQL Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer)

```
{
  repository(owner: {owner}, name: {name}) {
    object(oid: {oid}) {
      ... on Commit {
        parents(first: 10) {
          nodes {
            oid
            message
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Of course entering valid repo name and owner and commit hash (oid).